# FTP account Restrict to upload only photos

Tags: centos, ftp

How can I access a specific FTP account that has a folder in the public directory ?
Restrict to upload only photos?

I have centos7 server with WHM .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer in other site and question and just want post answer for other user :

if want to restrict file type :

```
<FilesMatch ".(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">

Order Allow,Deny

Deny from all

</FilesMatch>
```

or this for allow from all :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

or Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/.*\.(php|rb|py)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

The above will block any filename ending in .php or .rb or .py in the /uploads directory or its subdirectories. For example, it will block:

- something.php more.php